# jclouds - use authentication v1 for openstack-swift?

Tags: java, openstack-swift, jclouds

I have an openstack-swift blob store set up with v1 authentication that I wish to access via jclouds.  Is there a way to do this?

(As far as I can tell, the KeystoneAuthenticationModule is always installed.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to do this with jclouds. Try this:

```
    ContextBuilder builder = ContextBuilder
        .newBuilder("swift")
        .credentials(IDENTITY, CREDENTIAL)
        .endpoint(ENDPOINT);
    BlobStoreContext blobStoreContext = builder.build(
        BlobStoreContext.class);
    BlobStore blobStore = blobStoreContext.getBlobStore();
```

Replace IDENTITY, CREDENTIAL, ENDPOINT above with the appropriate values.

After this you can use the blobStore object for actual blobstore operations such as createContainer, getBlob, putBlob, etc.

Comment: yes, this works - I was using provider "openstack-swift" instead of "swift"

Comment: That snippet throw error for openstack-swift api 1.8.0 `java.util.NoSuchElementException: key [swift] not in the list of providers or apis: {apis=[transient, stub, openstack-cinder, openstack-glance, openstack-keystone, openstack-marconi, openstack-neutron-legacy, openstack-neutron, openstack-nova, openstack-swift, openstack-trove]}`